# SilverStripe renaming uploaded file only for specific field

Tags: silverstripe

I have extended CMS settings to upload two CSS files. Part of the `SiteConfig` extension code -

```
<?php

//OTHER CODES HERE
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $cssfile = UploadField::create(
    'StyleSheet',
    'Style Sheet'
));

$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $clientcssfile = UploadField::create(
    'ClientStyleSheet',
    'Client Style Sheet'
));
//OTHER CODES HERE
?>
```

And i have extended the `File` class

```
class FileRenameExtension extends DataExtension {

    function onAfterUpload() {

        $file = $this->owner;
        $file->Name = 'CustomStyle.'.$file->getExtension();
        $file->write();
    }   

}
```

**PROBLEM**

1. The code renames the file uploaded from all the fields, but I want to rename the files uploaded from `ClientStyleSheet` only.
2. Before it renames the file, if user uploads file with name that already exists, it warns, and if I click `Overwrite`, it overwrites the files and renames the file. I just want no matter what is the file name, it just saves the file with name that is specified in the `File Extension Class`
3. What is the proper way to rename file before its get uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

You better use `FileField` directly in your case with custom upload() action handler.

Answer (score 0):

With the DataExtension, you modify all instances of File, wherever they are uploaded.

One possible solution: You subclass File and hook into onAfterUpload:

```
class CSSFile extends File {
    function onAfterUpload() {
        $file = $this;
        $file->Name = 'CustomStyle.'.$file->getExtension();
        $file->write();
        parent::onAfterUpload();
    }      
}
```

Now you use this in your SiteConfig, it should work with UploadField just like a standard File.

If I understand it correctly, you want to enable the user to add a stylesheet to the site. A different solution would then be to allow any filenames and to use the original filename in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="$SiteConfig.StyleSheet.URL">
```

I would prefer to use this second solution.